# Overriding Magento 2 base empty page_layout

Tags: xml, magento2

I'm currently working on a custom storefront design for a Magento 2 store and I'm trying to implement a theme which does not inherit from a base theme and where I can define my own `page_layout` files without having to extend anything. For example, currently Magento uses the following chain of inheritance with its layouts... `empty.xml` -> `1_column.xml` -> `2_columns.xml` etc.

What I want to achieve is to completely override the `empty.xml` so I can define my own layout starting with the `root` container. As it stands, I have managed to get my own `empty.xml` layout to appear in the backend and set it as a layout for pages, however, it'll error out alerting me to having multiple elements of the same name within the layout (in this case, it's `content`). This tells me that I am not overriding properly.

I have tried adding my declarations at the following directories...

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/layout/override/base/empty.xml
```

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml
```

I have had no luck with either.

I have no reason to believe this is an unreasonable approach to developing a custom front and any help would be greatly appreciated.